# Make environment which calls a function

Tags: environments

I'm trying to make an environment that does the follows:

```
\newcommand\foo[1]{does something with #1}

\newenvironment{bar}{\foo \someStartFunction}{\someEndFunction}
```

such that

```
\begin{bar}
some text
\end{bar}
```

expands to

```
\foo{some text}
```

My first instinct would be to place brackets { and } inside the newenvironment, but this will of course go wrong. Is there any easy way to do this; is there some kind of \someStartFunction ... \someEndFunction?

Comment: You are looking for the `environ` package.

Comment: @egreg Right, thank you very much. These kind of things are so difficult to find with Google since I usually don't know the correct English search terms.

Comment: Don't worry! It was a perfectly legitimate question: searching the site is not that easy if you don't know what to look for.